# Argmin operation on loss function of a matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, maxima-minima, robust-statistics

I'm trying to solve the following equation for $\beta$, the only unknown in the equation. I have two questions.

1. I'm not quite sure how a matrix could fit into the Huber loss function and subsequent argmin operation. I am thinking I'm supposed to treat $\dfrac{1}{2}x$ and $\zeta|x|$ like a scalar multiplication on a matrix, but I'm not sure what I am minimizing in this case because the norm of the matrix is taken outside of the argmin function.
2. Is my goal to find a single $\beta$ that minimizes over all k or $N^{'}-1$ number of $\beta_k$s for each k? I am thinking it might be the later because argmin operation is within $P_k^M$ instead of $P^M$.

$
k = 0, 1, 2, \dots{}, N^{'}-1
$

$
N^{'} = 2N
$

$
 P_k^M = 
 \dfrac{N^{'}}{4}
 |argmin_\beta \Gamma({\phi_k \beta - \mathrm{x}})|^2
$

$\Gamma (x) = 
\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2}x & |x| \leq \zeta \\ \zeta|x|-\dfrac{1}{2}\zeta^2  & |x| > \zeta
\end{cases}$ for some hyperparameter $\zeta$

$
\phi_k=  
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(0) & sin(0) \\
cos(2\pi k / N^{'}) & sin(2\pi k / N^{'}) \\
cos(4\pi k / N^{'}) & sin(4\pi k / N^{'}) \\
\vdots{} & \vdots{} \\
cos(2(N^{'}-1)\pi k / N^{'}) & sin(2(N^{'}-1)\pi k / N^{'})
\end{bmatrix} 
$

$
\beta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{0, t = 0} & \beta_{0, 1} & \dots{} & \beta_{0, N^{'}-1} \\
\beta_{1, t = 0} & \beta_{1, 1} & \dots{} & \beta_{1, N^{'}-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\mathrm{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{j=0, t=0} & \dots{} & w_{0, N-1} & 0 & \dots{} & 0     \\
& \vdots{}& \ddots{}               & & \vdots{} &         \\
w_{N^{'}-1, 0} & \dots{} & w_{N^{'}-1, N-1} & 0 & \dots{} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

The algorithm I am trying to implement is [RobustPeriod: Time-Frequency Mining for Robust Multiple Periodicity Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.09535)